# deliberate infinite loop in useEffect keeps running after component unload?

Tags: reactjs

I need to have an infinite loop inside a useEffect for a continual process, however when the component gets unloaded  the loop keeps going, I also have issues with the setTimeout cleanup and setTimeout violations in the console .. I have tried to use a cleanup function but to no avail?

```
  function delay(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  }

useEffect(() => {
animate();
    const animate = async (dates) => {
      let i = 0;
      await delay(5000);
      while (true) {
        console.log("setting");        
        await delay(1500);
        if (i === dates.length - 1) {
          i = 0;
        } else {
          i++;
        }
      }     
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer's close, but if you want it to run continuously, what you need is `setInterval()` [(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval). While also saving its ID to clear it on clean up.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  let interval;
  animate();
  const animate = (dates) => {
    let i = 0;
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("setting");
      if (i === dates.length - 1) {
        i = 0;
      } else {
        i++;
      }
    }, 1500)    
  };
  return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, []);
```

Comment: Might have to declare `interval` before you define `animate`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the timeout in memory and clear it in the [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) of the effect.

Here is a simplified example (also see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t9myLbkv/)):

```
function Animate() {
  const [i, setI] = useState(1)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => setI(v => v + 1), 100)
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
  }, [i]) // Be sure to include `i` in dependency array

  return <>{i}</>
}
```

As others suggested, using an interval instead of a timeout will work too. Maybe even better.

Comment: animate is not the component and I'm setting multiple timers every loop, the issue is not just the settimeout either, the loop keeps running even after the component is unloaded, or are you saying the animate should be a component ?

Comment: My answer is to not even use a loop. Animate doesn't need to be a component, that was just an example. Without more context it's hard to determine the best solution.